# Limits of an odd degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, polynomials

> Let $P(x)= a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$, where $n$ is odd and $a_n$ is positive. Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{ x\to+\infty}P(x)=+\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{ x\to-\infty}P(x)=-\infty$

I have seen the previous property being used to prove other statements, so I decided to prove it. However, I did not succeed. Any help is welcome

Comment: This might answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232145/prove-that-a-polynomial-diverges-to-infinity

You would need the fact that $n$ is odd for the $x\to-\infty$ case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by making it a bit simpler by noting that
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n x^n + \cdots +a_0)=\lim_{x\to \infty} x^n(a_n + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{x^n}) = a_n \lim_{x \to \infty} x^n.
$$

Now you just need to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pm \infty} x^n = \pm \infty$, for odd $n$. Using the definition,
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} x^n = + \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall_{M>0} \exists_{S>0}:x>S \Rightarrow x^n > M 
$$

Lets fix $M>0$. Since $x^n>M \Leftrightarrow x > \sqrt[n]{M}$, we just need to take $S=\sqrt[n]{M}$, which completes the proof.

Similarly,

$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} x^n = - \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall_{M>0} \exists_{S>0}:x < -S \Rightarrow x^n < -M 
$$

Again, fixing $M>0$, since for odd $n$ we have that $x^n < -M \Leftrightarrow x < -\sqrt[n]{M}$, we just set $S=\sqrt[n]{M}$ and the result follows.